# Launch iOS app without setting up URL Scheme

Tags: ios, url, launch

Goodmorning,
there is a way to launch an iOS app from Safari without create a custom URL scheme, such as the method of Smart App Banners, that do it automatically only with App ID?

Thanks to all.

Comment: Have you tried adding a [Smart App Banner meta tag](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051-CH6-SW2) at the top of whatever web page you want to load into Safari?  I'm assuming you want to do it from some web page since you say you want to launch using Safari.

Comment: I'm tring to set the string to launch my app directly from Facebook app if it's already installed. Example: itms:// to launch iTunes Store.